# Missing required parameters for [Route: home.destinationsDetailCategory] [URI: destinations/{slug}/{category}]

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-6

I am not an expert in programming, I just deploy Laravel projects to the server, but I get errors after everything is deployed. I'm using Laravel Framework 6.20.5 I have a named route

```
Route::get('/destinations/{slug}/{category}', 'HomeController@destinationsDetailCategory')->name('home.destinationsDetailCategory');
```

These are my homestays/resources/views/partials/header.blade.php code :

```
 @foreach( $headerDestination as $city )
<a class="d-block w-50 p-2 dropdown-item" href="{{ route('home.destinationsDetailCategory', [$city->slug, 'attraction'])}}">{{ $city->name }}</a>
 @endforeach
```

. What is my error? Thank you!

I tried modifying the value of the $city->slug parameter to handle null values and added the null coalescing operator to provide a default value if the slug is null. My expectation was to avoid the 'Missing required parameters' error for the 'home.destinationsDetailCategory' route. However, what actually happened is that the error message still appears, and the generated URL does not match the expected one."

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to Composer itself? Also, please keep in mind that Laravel v6 is EOL since more than a year, please upgrade your application to check whether this is a bug in Laravel that got fixed in the meantime

Comment: I tried deleting the database and re-uploading it, initially there were no errors and the display was normal but a few weeks later an error appeared even though nothing had changed, I know this version is too old because Laravel upgrades cannot be instant, maybe the last option for upgrading.

Comment: Still the error after updating to the latest Laravel version
https://ibb.co/NnwD9fR

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@foreach( $headerDestination as $city )
   <a class="d-block w-50 p-2 dropdown-item" href="{{ route('home.destinationsDetailCategory', ['slug' => $city->slug, 'category' => 'attraction'])}}">{{ $city->name }}</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I've tried it still has an error